# Passenger ruby on rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

so i just finished my app and im uploading my projecto to my production server and when i run the command passenger-install-apache2-module
 im getting this error

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2158:in `method_missing': undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0xd50cc8 passenger-5.0.30> (NoMethodError)
```

what can i do to fix this ?

Comment: There should be more error message than that!

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too.  For me, the error does not happen if I run the binary with the full path to the binary in the passenger gem directory.

Probably something like :

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module

in your case.

After posting this, I found this:

https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1420

Answer (score -1):

I try this and work for me:

```
gem update --system
```